# Add 2 functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add my getExamGrades and getLabGrades together by calling my other function to get a total grade but nothing I've tried works. Everything I've done so far just eliminates both of the functions I call and leaves everything blank. The code below works perfectly fine, just need help with the last part and then I can figure out the other variables and functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script>

function getExamGrades()
{
var exam1 = document.getElementById("Exam1").value;
var exam2 = document.getElementById("Exam2").value;
var exam3 = document.getElementById("Exam3").value;
var Exams = Number(exam1) + Number(exam2) + Number(exam3);
document.getElementById("examGrade").innerHTML = Exams;

}
function getLabGrades()
{
var lab1 = document.getElementById("Lab1").value;
var lab2 = document.getElementById("Lab2").value;       
var lab3 = document.getElementById("Lab3").value;

var Labs = Number(lab1) + Number(lab2) + Number(lab3);
document.getElementById("labGrade").innerHTML = Labs;
}
function getTotalGrades()
{
 //var Total = Number(getExamGrades()) + Number(getLabGrades();
 document.getElementByID("totalGrade").innerHTML = Total;
 }

</script>
</header>
<body>

Exam1: <input type = "text" name="Exam1" value ="100" id="Exam1">
Exam2: <input type = "text" name="Exam2" value ="100" id="Exam2">
Exam3: <input type = "text" name="Exam3" value ="100" id="Exam3">
<br><br>
<button onClick="getExamGrades()"> Calculate Exam Grade </button>
Total: <output id="examGrade"> </output>
<br><br>
Lab1: <input type = "text" name="Lab1" value ="100" id="Lab1">
Lab2: <input type = "text" name="Lab2" value ="100" id="Lab2">
Lab3: <input type = "text" name="Lab3" value ="100" id="Lab3"> 
<br><br>
<button onClick="getLabGrades()"> Calculate Lab Grade </button>
Total: <output id="labGrade"> </output>
<br><br>
<button onClick="getTotalGrades()"> Calculate Total Grade </button>
Final Grade: <output id="totalGrade"> </output>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, Cory. Your functions, `getExamGrades` and `getLabGrades` are not returning any values. They are setting some HTML elements' values, but not returning anything. Try returning `Exams` and `Labs` respectively and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: I did this and the first 2 functions work, but the getTotalGrades() still shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are not returning the values.  If they did, then what you were trying would work.  Try it like this:

```
function getExamGrades()
{
var exam1 = document.getElementById("Exam1").value;
var exam2 = document.getElementById("Exam2").value;
var exam3 = document.getElementById("Exam3").value;
var Exams = Number(exam1) + Number(exam2) + Number(exam3);
document.getElementById("examGrade").innerHTML = Exams;
return Exams;
}

function getLabGrades()
{
var lab1 = document.getElementById("Lab1").value;
var lab2 = document.getElementById("Lab2").value;       
var lab3 = document.getElementById("Lab3").value;

var Labs = Number(lab1) + Number(lab2) + Number(lab3);
document.getElementById("labGrade").innerHTML = Labs;
return Labs;
}

function getTotalGrades()
{
var Total = Number(getExamGrades()) + Number(getLabGrades());
document.getElementById("totalGrade").innerHTML = Total;
}
```

There were a couple of other minor issues that I fixed for you too.
You can see a working example here:    http://jsfiddle.net/8js5uewc/2/

Comment: I did this and the first 2 functions work, but the getTotalGrades() still shows nothing.

Comment: That is because the `getTotalGrades` function uses `document.getElementByID` - notice the final capital case `D`, which should be lower case.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the things that I fixed.  The other was that the button event should be `onclick` and not `onClick`.

Comment: I hate my life.. Thank you so much @paul23

Comment: Hope this helped you, @CoryDunagan.  Welcome to SO!